# Duplicate after group by and size

Tags: python

Here is [sample data from a pandas data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E68te.png)

but after I run the code

```
df.groupby('stock_name').size()
```

It shows [these results

stock_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frmw6.png)

I tried `df.str.replace(' ' ,'')` - results still same.

Comment: Even as deleting blanks (from all of the data frame?!) didn't have the desired effect, non-apparent characters are a valid guess.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if any column has preceding or post spaces which may have caused this issue

Comment: I already use df.str.replace(' ' ,'')  but the results still same